# Need Max values from the query?

Tags: sql

I have two tables

> Employee ( empid integer, mgrid integer, deptid integer, salary
>   integer)
>
> Dept (deptid integer, deptname text),

I am trying find to departments that have maximum number of employees. 
I tried this but i am getting all the dept Id's, how to get dept Id that has maximum employees.

```
SELECT dept.DeptName,
    COUNT(emp.EmpId) AS NUM_OF_EMPLOYEES
  FROM Dept dept
  INNER JOIN Employee emp
  ON dept.DeptId = emp.deptId
  GROUP BY dept.DeptName;
```

Comment: Is that MySQL or Oracle or Teradata?

Comment: I removed the extraneous database tags.  Feel free to add the tag for the database you are really using.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your DB, but the logic is the same. You want to sort the results, then just grab the top of the results.

In sql-server, Access, Teradata and a few other DB's you would use `TOP`:

```
SELECT TOP 1 dept.DeptName,
    COUNT(emp.EmpId) AS NUM_OF_EMPLOYEES
  FROM Dept dept
  INNER JOIN Employee emp
  ON dept.DeptId = emp.deptId
  GROUP BY dept.DeptName
  ORDER BY NUM_OF_EMPLOYEES DESC
```

On MySQL or Postgres you would use LIMIT:

```
  SELECT dept.DeptName,
    COUNT(emp.EmpId) AS NUM_OF_EMPLOYEES
  FROM Dept dept
  INNER JOIN Employee emp
  ON dept.DeptId = emp.deptId
  GROUP BY dept.DeptName
  ORDER BY NUM_OF_EMPLOYEES DESC
  LIMIT 1
```

In Oracle you use RowNum:

```
  SELECT dept.DeptName,
    COUNT(emp.EmpId) AS NUM_OF_EMPLOYEES
  FROM Dept dept
  INNER JOIN Employee emp
  ON dept.DeptId = emp.deptId
  WHERE ROWNUM=1
  GROUP BY dept.DeptName
  ORDER BY NUM_OF_EMPLOYEES DESC
```

Comment: If i have more than one rows with max no of employees, I need to get all of those, how can i do that ?CBC 9
ABC 9
BBC 1 In this case i need to get CBC and ABC..

Comment: Understood. In that case, it's best that you update the question with the RDBMS that you are using. Postgres, ms sql-server, and Teradata have some Window Functions that would help out here. Otherwise, you could go with the subquery to find the max() number and then use that to restrict your results.

Comment: I'm working on Oracle. Can you please tell me how to write with subquery?

Comment: I tried writing subquery with max() didn't work, i didn't wrote subqueries before. can you please help me with that @JNevil